# Repeat disk failure in Dell PC

Tags: hard-drive, dell-dimension

I have an older Dell E520 that I've been using as a sort of development server.  Over the last 6 months I've had two hard drives and 2 DVD drives fail in this box.

Is this just really bad luck?  Is this box just cursed, or could there be something else causing the failures?  Maybe a bad power supply?

Comment: Either a bad PSU or really nasty AC supplying it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad power supply, or even bad power to the system, causing over- or under-volting.

Replace your power supply, and run off clean power (you can get a reasonable UPS for a reasonable price).

Comment: Incidentally, I refer to undervolting as "brownouts" and get funny looks. What does everyone else call that?

Comment: I've always said "brownout", but undervolting is more obvious, I guess. Probably the safest option.

Comment: I guess it's just semantics, and funny looks aren't always a bad thing. At least you get noticed :-)